# Scraping life history data from Encyclopedia of Life

Tags: python, web-scraping, text-mining

I am an environmental scientist with some coding experience.

This is my first attempt at text scraping.

I am trying to pull certain life history data from the Encyclopedia of Life's traitbank database.

For example, if I want to collect the "life span" information for every organism available:

[Life Span Search](http://eol.org/data_search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&taxon_concept_id=&attribute=http%3A%2F%2Fpurl.obolibrary.org%2Fobo%2FPATO_0000050&commit=Search&taxon_name=&q=)

I have been learning BeautifulSoup, but I'm just not sure the most efficient way of doing this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So which part are you stuck on exactly?

Comment: The site has a free api: http://eol.org/info/api_overview . There really is no point in scraping the site when you can get the data nicely formatted in JSON or XML.

Comment: I'm looking at the API now. I've only crunched numbers in R before, so this is all new to me. Using text scraping, I was having difficultly just getting the text